# Laravel Undefined Method

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error on my query when the interest method exists in my model.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::interest()

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);

    $interests = Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->interest()->get();

    return view('dashboard')->with('space', $user->space)->with('interest', $interests->space);
}
```

**Space Model:**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function interest(){
    return $this->hasMany(Interest::class);
}
```

**Interest Model:**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function interest(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Space::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,
First of all you can access authenticated user id by this `auth()->id()`

For relationship in controller

```php
    $interests = Space::with(['interest'])->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

For more 
[Laravel eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->interest()->get();
```

The Line Shows Error Because the method `interest` is not existed in query builder or Model Scopes

But I think You have Misundestood something

Loading Relation In collection

```
Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('interest')->get();
```

Will Work

And

```
$singleFind = Space::findOrFail($yourId)->interest();
```

Will Work as you expected

Hope its clear